# JBoss automatically undeploys EJBs

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jboss

we have a situation at office. JBoss automatically unloads all deployed EJB's without us knowing why.

here's the log we got :

```
2009-11-09 15:59:51,375 INFO  [org.jboss.system.server.Server] JBoss (MX MicroKernel)      [4.2.1.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_1_GA date=200707131605)] Started in 14s:704ms

2009-11-09 15:59:51,390 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLogger] Periodic     recovery - first pass 
2009-11-09 15:59:51,406 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLogger] StatusModule:     first pass 
2009-11-09 15:59:51,406 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.txoj.logging.txojLoggerI18N]     [com.arjuna.ats.internal.txoj.recovery.TORecoveryModule_3] - TORecoveryModule - first pass
2009-11-09 15:59:51,406 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N]     [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.info.firstpass] Local XARecoveryModule - first pass
2009-11-09 16:00:01,406 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLogger] Periodic     recovery - second pass 
2009-11-09 16:00:01,406 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.logging.arjLogger]     AtomicActionRecoveryModule: Second pass 
2009-11-09 16:00:01,406 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.txoj.logging.txojLoggerI18N]     [com.arjuna.ats.internal.txoj.recovery.TORecoveryModule_6] - TORecoveryModule - second pass
2009-11-09 16:00:01,406 DEBUG [com.arjuna.ats.jta.logging.loggerI18N]     [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.info.secondpass] Local XARecoveryModule - second pass


2009-11-09 16:00:42,796 DEBUG [org.jboss.system.ServiceController] destroying service:     persistence.units:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,unitName=grh
2009-11-09 16:00:42,796 DEBUG [org.jboss.system.ServiceController] Destroy requested     before stop, calling stop now for service:     persistence.units:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,unitName=grh
2009-11-09 16:00:42,796 DEBUG [org.jboss.system.ServiceController] stopping service:     persistence.units:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,unitName=grh
2009-11-09 16:00:42,796 DEBUG [org.jboss.system.ServiceController] stopping dependent         services for:     persistence.units:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,unitName=grh dependent     services are: [ObjectName:     jboss.j2ee:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,name=GestEvaluation,service=EJB3
      State: RUNNING
      I Depend On:
        persistence.units:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,unitName=grh
    , ObjectName:     jboss.j2ee:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,name=GestionUtilisateur,service=E    JB3
       State: RUNNING
      I Depend On:
        persistence.units:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,unitName=grh
    ]
2009-11-09 16:00:42,796 DEBUG [org.jboss.system.ServiceController] stopping service:     jboss.j2ee:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,name=GestEvaluation,service=EJB3
2009-11-09 16:00:42,796 DEBUG [org.jboss.system.ServiceController] stopping dependent     services for:     jboss.j2ee:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,name=GestEvaluation,service=EJB3     dependent services are: []
2009-11-09 16:00:42,796 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessDelegateWrapper]     Stopping     jboss.j2ee:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,name=GestEvaluation,service=EJB3
2009-11-09 16:00:42,796 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.EJBTimerServiceImpl]     removeTimerService: org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.TimerServiceImpl@134329b
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB:      com.afrikbrain.grh.ejb.session.GestEvaluation ejbName: GestEvaluation
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessDelegateWrapper]     Stopped     jboss.j2ee:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,name=GestEvaluation,service=EJB3
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 DEBUG [org.jboss.system.ServiceController] stopping service:     jboss.j2ee:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,name=GestionUtilisateur,service=E    JB3
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 DEBUG [org.jboss.system.ServiceController] stopping dependent     services for:     jboss.j2ee:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,name=GestionUtilisateur,service=E    JB3 dependent services are: []
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessDelegateWrapper]     Stopping     jboss.j2ee:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,name=GestionUtilisateur,service=E     JB3
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.EJBTimerServiceImpl]     removeTimerService: org.jboss.ejb.txtimer.TimerServiceImpl@1da817b
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.EJBContainer] STOPPED EJB:     com.afrikbrain.grh.ejb.session.GestionUtilisateur ejbName: GestionUtilisateur
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb3.stateless.StatelessDelegateWrapper]     Stopped     jboss.j2ee:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,name=GestionUtilisateur,service=E    JB3
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb3.ServiceDelegateWrapper] Stopping     persistence.units:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,unitName=grh
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 INFO  [org.jboss.ejb3.entity.PersistenceUnitDeployment]     Stopping persistence unit     persistence.units:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,unitName=grh
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 INFO  [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl] closing
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 INFO  [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory]     Unbinding factory from JNDI name:     persistence.units:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,unitName=grh
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 INFO  [org.hibernate.util.NamingHelper] JNDI InitialContext     properties:  {java.naming.factory.initial=org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory,   java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces}
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 INFO  [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory] Unbound     factory from JNDI name:     persistence.units:ear=prjGRHProcess.ear,jar=prjGRHProcessEJB.jar,unitName=grh
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] Running  hbm2ddl schema export
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 DEBUG [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] import file   not found: /import.sql
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] exporting     generated schema to database
2009-11-09 16:00:42,812 DEBUG [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] drop table      TBA_ACT_TRANSMISSION cascade constraints
2009-11-09 16:00:42,828 DEBUG [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] drop table     TBA_DEST_TRANSMISSION cascade constraints
2009-11-09 16:00:42,843 DEBUG [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] drop table     TBA_DOMAINE_PROFIL cascade constraints
2009-11-09 16:00:42,859 DEBUG [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] drop table     TBA_EMPLOYE_UM cascade constraints
2009-11-09 16:00:42,875 DEBUG [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] drop table TBA_MANAGERS_UM cascade constraints
2009-11-09 16:00:42,890 DEBUG [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] drop table TB_ACTION cascade constraints
2009-11-09 16:00:42,906 DEBUG [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport] drop table TB_DMDDEROGATION cascade constraints
```

Comment: I may be blind be I can't see anything in the log that could help answering the question. Did you skip the interesting parts or what?

Comment: What version of jboss is this? I imagine its the community edition or redhat would have been contacted. Did someone execute a script accidently?

Comment: that is all I can see on the log file.

Comment: after starting, the JBoss server then starts to unload its EJBs after a while.

Comment: this is jboss-4.2.1.GA . it occurs on many of our servers.

Comment: I don't know wether someone executed a script or not, I'm not sure.

Comment: Is this a recurring issue?  For instance every 3rd Monday of the month at midnight?  If you could post up some more of the logs this may be easier to diagnose.  Also check your code logs to see if some block of code executed which forced JBoss to restart.

Comment: no, it seems to be totally random.

Comment: I can post the whole logs. but it would be too much here ...

Comment: pastebin away my friend

Answer (score 0):

Set the logging level to [TRACE](http://www.jboss.org/community/wiki/UsageOfLoggingLevels) maybe can help.

BTW, I see a similar problem with ejbs compiled with jdk1.4, deployed in a jboss running in jdk1.5. Please check the jdk versions.